# When building NuGet packages, VS pretends elements in the csproj file like <Deterministic> and <EmbedUntrackedSources> don't exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, csproj

I'm trying to add NuGet package-related metadata to some csproj files in some .NET Standard 2.0 projects, and some of the tags I'm trying to use include things like `Deterministic` and `EmbedUntrackedSources`.  For example:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    ...
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

However when I try to publish a project like that as a newly created NuGet package, things like the `Deterministic` tag are completely ignored.  If I inspect the package through NuGet Package Explorer, it'll raise multiple red flags in the Health section.  For example, it'll place a red icon by "Deterministic (dll/exe)", and it'll claim that it's non-deterministic.

The problem is that I specifically added the tag to the csproj file and set it to true.  One thing I did notice though is that Intellisense worked fine for some more basic tags, such as `Title` and `Company`, but it did not work at all for `Deterministic`.  Intellisense doesn't work for some other tags either, such as `EmbedUntrackedSources`.

(I'm loosely following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCGlSt1WAOo), and these tags are brand new to me.)

What's the problem?  What would make a pretty up-to-date instance of Visual Studio fail to recognize these tags?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path, and are probably missing a few additional properties.

Here's an example of a project that does satisfy the NuGet Package Explorer's deterministic checks:

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/blob/master/Directory.Build.props
https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/blob/master/Directory.Build.targets

It's possible you need the workaround found in that `.targets` file. If you create a file called `Directory.Build.targets` in your solution folder, it should be picked up automatically.

If this is an open source project, are you also referencing SourceLink?

The IntelliSense issues are unrelated. What version of Visual Studio are you using? If it's the latest version, I will file an issue against MSBuild who control the schema used for IntelliSense (from memory).